# What size socket to use on a 2002 ford explorer 4.6L V8 engine

Tags: ford, sparkplugs, explorer

I can't seem to get a socket to catch on the spark plug. I'm told it is a 5/8" or could it be 9/16"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is definitely a 5/8" and yes push the inner rubber of the socket all the way up as it may stop you from getting a full contact/grip on the plug it's self. Be careful as they can break easily, I do it on a cold engine add a little WD40 down there wait a few and crack it one good tug.

Comment: YES- I could not answer any better, However I have no problem with removal on a warm engine, Which I prefer unless it has been sitting a while.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a 5/8" socket. If using a spark plug socket, make sure the rubber insert isn't causing you issues. Spark plugs usually only come in one of two sizes: 5/8" or 13/16". The one showing I saw from a parts listing is 5/8".